# Two different $_GET variables on SWITCH (PHP)

Tags: php, variables, get, switch-statement

Im using Switch statment to change the content of my page, like this:

```
$id=$_GET['id'];
$n = $_GET['n'];          
switch ($id) {
    case 0:
        include("news.php");   
        break;      
    case 1:
        include("newsdetail.php?n=".$n);
        break;                                                                                            
    default:  
        include("news.php");
}
```

In news.php i show all the existing news like this:

```
    while($myrow = mysqli_fetch_array($result)){
    echo "<table>
            <tr>
             <td><img width='200' heigth='115' src='images/".$myrow['smallimage'].".jpg'/></td>
             <td>
             <b>".$myrow['title']."</b>
              <br />
             <i>By ".$myrow['author'].", ".$myrow['date']."</i>
              <br />
             ".$myrow['preview']."<br>
             <a href='index.php?id=1&n=".$myrow['id']."'><b>READ</b></a>
             </td>
            </tr>
           </table>";
}
```

And insidetails.php:

```
    $idnews = $_GET['n'];
$sql = "SELECT * FROM news WHERE id='$idnews'";
$result = mysqli_query($db,$sql);
while($myrow = mysqli_fetch_array($result)){
    echo    $myrow['title']."<br>
            <i>Por ".$myrow['author']."</i><br>
            ".$myrow['date']."<br>
            <img src='images/".$myrow['bigimage'].".jpg'>
            ".$myrow['body']."";
}
```

When I try this I get an url like `.../index.php?id=1&n=1` but shows no content. Everything works fine when tested alone.
Is it possible to make something like this and mak it work?

Comment: I don't think you can pass a querystring to `include` but you could just include the file, then use `$_GET` to get `n` again inside that file.

Comment: @FDL is indeed correct. `file_get_contents` will work, but you're not including it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can't do includes like this:

```
case 1:
    include("newsdetail.php?n=".$n);
    break;
```

This will have PHP trying to find a file called `newsdetail.php?n=1`, so there's no content showing up.

But there's no need to do it that way; your included file can still access the $_GET variables - like $_POST and so on, they're global, and so can be accessed anywhere in your code.

And just a note to be wary; you're passing a value from `$_GET` directly into a query. This opens you up to SQL injection issues. You should look at using mysqli_ or PDO, both of which help you write code that's a lot more secure.

Comment: I only deleted the 'n=".$n' and worked perfectly! Thanks for the clarification and the headsup too, ill be doing something about it.

Comment: I'm glad I could help. If you need any more help, feel free to ask!

Answer (score 1):

There are quite a few problems with your code. I will try to address them one by one.

- First of all, you are widely open to a [SQL Injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection). Always use
  prepared statements and parameterized queries.
- You are mixing SQL with your logic and even presentation code. You should put that in completely different classes as each class should have just one responsibility. This also makes your code much more maintainable and you can reuse your code instead of copy pasting it (violating the [DRY](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don%27t_repeat_yourself) principle). An example of this concept is the [MVC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model%E2%80%93view%E2%80%93controller) pattern.
- To access the different parts of your application you should use the [front controller](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Front_Controller_pattern) pattern (it seems like you are already doing that). So that is good. Now you could use an [autoloader](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.autoload.php) which will automatically load the required files. I recommend using [namespaces](http://php.net/namespaces) and using a [PSR-0 autoloader](https://github.com/php-fig/fig-standards/blob/master/accepted/PSR-0.md).
- Now you still need to route the request to the right class method (controller if you are using MVC). I recommend you use one of many available libraries like that, for example [klein](https://github.com/chriso/klein.php). If you want to write your own, at least look at the code of some routing libraries and see how they are doing it.

I know this is a lot but I hope you take the time to learn about the concepts I described above. Don't worry if you don't understand everything the first time. And if you have any questions, ask away.

Comment: You gave me a lot of homework haha thanks a lot for the info, Im with a lot of free time so Ill be reading this before to continue coding my page. Thanks!